# aiohttp: separate request sending from response waiting

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a specific use case where I need to send an HTTP request **ASAP**, but cannot wait for the HTTP response to come back before doing some necessary work.

*Conceptually*, I need to do this:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    request = await session.send_request(method='GET', url='https://httpbin.org/get')
    # do some necessary work
    response = await request.get_response()
    # process response...
```

The problem with the simple plain way is, I can send the HTTP request as soon as I want, but I cannot yield while waiting for the response:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # this blocks until both the request is sent AND response arrived
    response = await session.request(method='GET', url='https://httpbin.org/get')
    # process response...
```

I tried to spin up a new coroutine so as to not have to wait for the HTTP response to arrive:

```py
async def foo(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
         # process response...

asyncio.create_task(foo('https://httpbin.org/get'))
# do necessary work
```

but then since `create_task()` occurs at "the first chance the event loop gets", it's sometimes half a second or a second after I call `create_task()`, which is too slow for my purpose.

My question(s):

(a) is there a way to separate HTTP request sending from HTTP response waiting in `aiohttp`?

(b) if not, can you suggest an alternative way to send HTTP request ASAP but to `await` the response asynchronously?

Thanks!

### Update #1

From @Isabi's suggestion in the comments, I tried only using `await` after the necessary work is done, but the HTTP request is never sent until the `await` is used, e.g.:

```py
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # send out an HTTP request that takes ~2 seconds before response comes back
    request = session.request(method='GET', url='https://httpbin.org/delay/2')
    await asyncio.sleep(4)  # simulate 4 seconds of necessary work
    # the following line still takes 2 seconds, indicating the request
    # didnt go out before `await` is used
    response = await request
    # process response...
```

### Update #2

I worked out a way that makes my application behave the way I want it (send the HTTP request ASAP, but don't block waiting for the HTTP response). The solution uses a call to `asyncio.sleep(0)`, inspired from [this thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue34476). However, it is not aesthetically satisfying:

```py
async def foo(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
         # process response...

asyncio.create_task(foo('https://httpbin.org/get'))
await asyncio.sleep(0)
# do necessary work
```

It doesn't feel right to me that what should be a not uncommon use case requires such an inelegant solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried removing the await keywork? That should be pausing the event loop until the response is received. You can then await it later and get the response after the important stuff you have to do

Comment: Good suggestion @Isabi; however I did try and without the `await` keyword, the HTTP request is **not** sent out. Nothing happens networking-wise until `await` is used

Comment: Eventually it will start. The idea is to initialize it and if the computer has time and resources it will get a response. My point is that you may initialize the request, do the stuff you have to do and only after await for the response. This way, you'll start a coroutine, do you things and then wait for the coroutine to end and retrieve the result. **EDIT** see https://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the task is being run half a second or even one second later? Because that should not be the case unless the loop is **busy** and the loop shouldn't be busy unless it's under **heavy load** or you have **blocking code** running at the same time.
You can use logging to check exactly when the request is being sent and when it's received:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(message)s", datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", level=logging.INFO)


async def foo(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         logging.info("request started")
         response = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
         logging.info("response received")
         text = await response.text()
         logging.info(f"response read {len(text)} bytes")
         # process response...


async def test():
    logging.info("sleep 0.1")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    logging.info("create task")
    asyncio.create_task(foo("https://httpbin.org/get"))
    logging.info("task created, sleep 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    logging.info("finished")


if __name__== "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

Output:

```
2020-06-10 10:52:00.017 INFO sleep 0.1
2020-06-10 10:52:00.118 INFO create task
2020-06-10 10:52:00.118 INFO task created, sleep 2
2020-06-10 10:52:00.119 INFO request started
2020-06-10 10:52:00.621 INFO response received
2020-06-10 10:52:00.622 INFO response read 308 bytes
2020-06-10 10:52:02.121 INFO finished
```

Notice the coroutine starts running about **1 ms** after creating it and the HTTP request takes about 0.5 seconds to complete; since 0.5 value is close to what you were seeing I believe you were measuring the time to complete the request and not the time to start the request.

Comment: Thanks Ionut, good question. >99% of the time, the task is ran <= 1 ms after it is created indeed, confirmed using logging equivalent to your snippet. But when my application is processing burst of inbound messages (the remaining <1% of times), it can take up to 500-1000 ms before asyncio finally create the task, which is unacceptable for my use case. As phrased in my question, I need my application to stop everything it is doing and send the HTTP request ASAP, but then don't wait for the HTTP response (because it needs to go back to processing inbound messages)

Comment: How do you process the burst (what do you do with the inbound messages)? My guess is you're blocking the loop; you might need to organize them in batches and let the loop process other tasks between batches.